# How shall I convert SqlXml to XmlText?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, types

I am reading some data stored in Xml format in SQL Server database and I am using C# to read this data. We have a type called XmlText in System.Xml but it doesn't allow me to convert and store the data from SqlXml to XmlText. I need to copy the data from database in XML format to some object and then serialize that object. Then I need to send a collection of objects over the network. What is the solution here?

Comment: How do you *currently* read the data? Are you reading it via [`ExecuteXmlReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader.aspx)? or something else?

Comment: thats the problem ; i am not able to read the data from the database

Comment: String s = reader.GetString(6) works for String but XmlText xml = reader.GetSqlXml(7) dies not work.

Comment: Consider using XmlDocument, XDocument or XmlReader

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ultimately, there is no direct link between `SqlXml` and `XmlText` (and indeed, `XmlText` only represents a specific type of node, not xml). You are going to have to go down to `string` or `byte[]` level and back up again (since you aren't using the streaming reader). For example:

```
string xml = reader.GetSqlXml(7).Value;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

or:

```
string xml = reader.GetSqlXml(7).Value;
XElement el = XElement.Parse(xml);
```

---

or (perhaps more efficient) using the `XmlReader` API:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using(XmlReader xr = reader.GetSqlXml(7).CreateReader()) {
    doc.Load(xr);
}
```

and

```
XElement el;
using(XmlReader xr = reader.GetSqlXml(7).CreateReader()) {
    el = XElement.Load(xr);
}
```